# Can't check Mime Type in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, mime-types

I have written a CodeIgniter class controller to check the mimetype of a file. Here's my script

```
<?php
class test_file extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        @session_start();
        $this->load->library('encrypt');
        $this->load->helper('file');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $path="./post_files/Catherine_Part1.wmv";
        echo "<a href='".base_url().$path."'>Show</a>";
        if(function_exists('mime_content_type') &&$mode==0)
            echo mime_content_type($path);
        else if(function_exists('finfo_open')&&$mode==0)
        { 
            $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
            $mimetype = finfo_file($finfo, $path);
            echo $mimetype;
        }
        else
            echo "no functions working";
        echo get_mime_by_extension($path);
    }
}

?>
```

The issue is that it's always printing `no functions working`.

That means both of the `mime_content_type()` and `finfo_open()` functions exist. But how can that happen?

Also `echo get_mime_by_extension($path);` doesn't echo anything.

However the path file is totaly correct. If I click on the show a href anchor, then it plays the file in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path to the file used by php functions needs to be the absolute path in the file system of the server, not relative to the URL. Try echoing `getcwd()` from your page, and it should give you the absolute path to the directory.

Secondly, the reason your `if` statements aren't being entered is most likely because of the `&& $mode==0` part. Where are you declaring the `$mode` variable ?